# ASM (from ObjectWeb) not calculating MaxStack correctly even though ClassWriter( COMPUTE_MAX + COMPUTE_STACK ) is set

Tags: java, assembly, java-bytecode-asm

I am getting expected ClassVerifyErrors when attempting to load a class i have generated using ASM. On further inspection i can see that the jvm is correct and that the method is talking about has an invalid MAX_STACK value. THe strange thing is am using the auto calculate the stack and max local options so this should not be a problem...
The method with the invalid option is very simple and yet the result is bad bytecode.

I have written a class with the intended method and compared my asm generated class against what javac produces and the byte codes matchup with the only error being the max stack is 0 which is wrong while javac sets a value of 2.

Id like to avoid having to calculate tha max stack/locals myself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Max stack and variable calculation can produce the wrong results if bytecode is not valid. You can verify that by running generated code trough the [CheckClassAdapter](http://asm.ow2.org/asm32/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/util/CheckClassAdapter.html).

For example,

```
  ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
  // generate code into cw instance...

  PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
  CheckClassAdapter.verify(new ClassReader(cw.toByteArray()), true, pw);
```

Comment: Thanx Eugene for the answer and ASM :)

My problem was caused by failing to end the previously generated method and creating another which somehow meant the Generator instance was in a confused state.