# Wrong Stack Size calculated by ASM library

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm, bytecode-manipulation

I generate bytecodes using ASM library and 'Max stack size' for a method is left to be calculated automatically. During runtime,i found this value (max stack size) is not correct.

My source code is:

```
    ClassWriter cw = new ClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS);
     ....
    MethodType initType = MethodType.methodType(void.class, clsList);
    mv = cw.visitMethod(ACC_PUBLIC, "<init>", initType.toMethodDescriptorString(), null, null);
    mv.visitCode();
    mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
    mv.visitMethodInsn(INVOKESPECIAL, "java/lang/invoke/BaseTemplate", "<init>", "()V", false);
    for(int i=0; i< list.size(); i++){
        mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 0);
        mv.visitVarInsn(ALOAD, 1+i);
        mv.visitFieldInsn(PUTFIELD, className, list.get(i).name(), Utils.getFieldDesc(list.get(i).type()));
    }
    mv.visitInsn(RETURN);
    //mv.visitMaxs(2, 4);   //Verify succeeds if uncomment this line.
    mv.visitEnd();

     ....
    //Verify generated code before class loading..
    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(System.out);
    CheckClassAdapter.verify(new ClassReader(cw.toByteArray()), true, pw);

 Class<?> expClass =defineClass(..);
```

Above code will generate bytecodes:

```
    Classfile /C:/temp/TGWD.class
  Last modified Mar 11, 2015; size 403 bytes
  MD5 checksum f58b96ad4cb0bc9e62f2ae5e11e63e90
public class TGWD extends java.lang.invoke.BaseTemplate
  minor version: 0
  major version: 51
  flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_SUPER

Constant pool:
   #1 = Utf8               TGWD
   #2 = Class              #1             //  TGWD
   #3 = Utf8               java/lang/invoke/BaseTemplate
   #4 = Class              #3             //  java/lang/invoke/BaseTemplate
   #5 = Utf8               guard
   #6 = Utf8               Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
   #7 = Utf8               trueTarget
   #8 = Utf8               falseTarget
   #9 = Utf8               <init>
  #10 = Utf8               (Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;)V
  #11 = Utf8               ()V
  #12 = NameAndType        #9:#11         //  "<init>":()V
  #13 = Methodref          #4.#12         //  java/lang/invoke/BaseTemplate."<init>":()V
  #14 = NameAndType        #5:#6          //  guard:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #15 = Fieldref           #2.#14         //  TGWD.guard:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #16 = NameAndType        #7:#6          //  trueTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #17 = Fieldref           #2.#16         //  TGWD.trueTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #18 = NameAndType        #8:#6          //  falseTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #19 = Fieldref           #2.#18         //  TGWD.falseTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
  #20 = Utf8               eval
  #21 = Utf8               Code
{
  final java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle guard;
    flags: ACC_FINAL


  final java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle trueTarget;
    flags: ACC_FINAL


  final java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle falseTarget;
    flags: ACC_FINAL


  public TGWD(java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle, java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle, java.lang.invoke.MethodHandle);
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC

    Code:
      stack=0, locals=4, args_size=4
         0: aload_0       
         1: invokespecial #13                 // Method java/lang/invoke/BaseTemplate."<init>":()V
         4: aload_0       
         5: aload_1       
         6: putfield      #15                 // Field guard:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
         9: aload_0       
        10: aload_2       
        11: putfield      #17                 // Field trueTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
        14: aload_0       
        15: aload_3       
        16: putfield      #19                 // Field falseTarget:Ljava/lang/invoke/MethodHandle;
        19: return        

  public void eval();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC

    Code:
      stack=0, locals=1, args_size=1
         0: return        
}
```

The bytecode reports error:

```
org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.AnalyzerException: Error at instruction 0: Insufficient maximum stack size.
    at org.objectweb.asm.tree.analysis.Analyzer.analyze(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.verify(Unknown Source)
    at org.objectweb.asm.util.CheckClassAdapter.verify(Unknown Source)
```

because the construction method: 
       stack=0, locals=4, args_size=4

The correct stack size is 2.

There is another thread [ASM (from ObjectWeb) not calculating MaxStack correctly even though ClassWriter( COMPUTE_MAX + COMPUTE_STACK ) is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2235493/asm-from-objectweb-not-calculating-maxstack-correctly-even-though-classwriter), indicating the max stack size can be wrongly calcucated if bytecode in other place is invalid.

So for me, the questions are:

- Where is invalidate bytecodes in the generated file?
- I still perfer avoiding call visitMax(). Becuase there are a number of generated bytecode methods and manual calucation of these values is not an easy job.

Comment: Hi Shijie, I am also getting the same issue with ASM 5.0.3 and JDK 1.7 / 8. Do you get solution to resolve this issue?

Comment: @RameshSubramanian, better to initialize your ClassWriter with COMPUTE_MAX+COMpUter_stack option, and then validate your the bytecode sequence of a method you want generate. You will find information if something is not correct

Comment: Hi shijie, thans for your input. Also I tried the other options too, but no success. Please see the link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34506965/how-do-i-overcome-the-verifyerrorexpecting-a-stackmap-frame-for-a-jdk-7-8-app. I just recompiled the problematic class - **websocket/chat/ChatAnnotation** with java 1.8 with out any code change, it works.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can’t omit the call to `visitMax`. From the [documentation of `ClassWriter.COMPUTE_MAXS`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_MAXS):

> If this flag is set, then the arguments of the [visitMaxs](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html#visitMaxs(int,%20int)) method of the [MethodVisitor](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/MethodVisitor.html) returned by the [visitMethod](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#visitMethod(int,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])) method will be ignored, and computed automatically from the signature and the bytecode of each method.

In other words, when you specify the flag, you may pass in whatever you want, e.g. call `visitMax(-1,-1)` to emphasize that you are not providing the actual values, but you still have to call the method to trigger the computation of the correct values.

By the way, since you create a class file of version `51` you should specify [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) as I doubt that you want to create `StackMapTable` attributes manually. Note that [`COMPUTE_FRAMES`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_FRAMES) implies [`COMPUTE_MAXS`](http://asm.ow2.org/asm50/javadoc/user/org/objectweb/asm/ClassWriter.html#COMPUTE_MAXS) behavior.